# How does one work over FTP and public wifi securely?

Tags: security, netbeans, server, ftp, sftp

So I'm working on a project by connecting to an FTP server which hosts the project (webdev app project based in PHP).

However I want to go work from cafe's once in a while an not just from home and i was wondering how can I do that securely?

The FTP connection is encrypted with "Pure FTP" setting in Netbeans, and there's a username and password requirement from the FTP server.

I also have a running VPN service on my laptop.

Is this enough? Or should I secure it better? I tried to find information but my search did not yield sufficient information, so any reference will also be great.

Code@30

Comment: While I do not know Netbeans, *"Pure FTP"* most probably means **no** encryption.

Comment: VPN should be quite enough if all your traffic goes through it.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl So indeed "Pure FTP" was **NO** encryption. I have now changed it to Explicit FTP which, to my understanding, means i am now using an FTPS protocol.

I have also disabled any option for any different connection to the server (Requires the encrypted protocol).

Would you say i'm good at this point?

Comment: You should be fine now, as long as Netbeans warns you, when server TLS/SSL certificate changes/becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. FTP is plaintext protocol and public wifi is usually not encrypted if it is what you mean. You don't want to send passwords over this. But there are several way how to make it usable:

- Use SFTP or FTPS, which adds a layer of security to the file transfer protocol.
- Use VPN **to the network where the FTP server is** (not VPN to somewhere else -- you would be still tranfering the passwords from the other side of VPN).
- Use `stunnel`, SSH port forwarding or SSH SOCKS proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the references I will try to set this up properly.

Is the main concern in the matter the FTP access username and password?

Comment: no. The main concern is that it is not encrypted and (not only your password) is transferred in plain text.

Comment: OK.

Also - is SFTP set up in my server or in netbeans?

Comment: OK I have now managed to set my Plesk server to only accept explicit FTPS connections and have also adjust my netbeans connection setting to follow that.

Would you say i need more protection? Should I look into adding the stunnel option you mentioned (Does that go together with FTPS at all?).

and once again a lot of thanks for the advice!

Comment: Dear downvoter, thank you for your valuable feedback on this answer. Leaving a comment why did you do this would make it even more useful to understand each other in the terms of expectation from an answer on StackOverflow.